# Trouble with html form in drupal

Tags: html, forms, drupal

This is part of code I have problem with

```
if(user_is_logged_in())
{



    $cover='<form  method="post">
<input type="text" name="tekst" /><input type="submit" id="add" value="Dodaj adres okładki" />
</form></td></tr>';


}
        else
        {
            $cover=" ";
        }
        $description .= '<tr><td width="60px">Title</td><td>'.$this->getTytul().'</td><td rowspan="20" width="150px">'.$cover.'</td></tr>';
```

and I have to run that query when user click submit button

> db_query("INSERT INTO okladki_publikacji(id_publikacji,adres_okladki) VALUES(".$this->getId().",".$value_from_form.")");

but I have no idea how to do it in drupal 
What I want is run function with that query on action in form but how? action =add_cover()  doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Drupal has an amazing forms API that can help you doing this kind of stuff in a breeze.

Basically you define a form using this API and then define the function to be invoked once the user submits it and that's it. Here's an example on how to define the form:

```
function myformname_form($form, &$form_state){

  // define the input field
  $form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Dodaj adres okładki'),
  );

  // define the submit button
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Apply'),
  );

  return $form;

}
```

Then you define the function that will be executed once the form is executed. Function basically has to be named the same + "_submit" - Drupal will do the magic behind the scenes to tie it together.

```
function myformname_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
  // and this will be where you execute the query you wanted.

}
```

Would recommend installing [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) so you can inspect the form_state variable - that's where the input field value will be.

Now, you can just render the form on your code below using drupal_get_form like this:

```
$cover = " ";
if(user_is_logged_in()) {
    $form = drupal_get_form('myformname_form');
    $cover = render($form);
}
$description .= '<tr><td width="60px">Title</td><td>'.$this->getTytul().'</td><td rowspan="20" width="150px">'.$cover.'</td></tr>';
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, in fact this is the best way to make my form but i need render($form) in that line
$description .= '<tr><td width="60px">Title</td><td>'.$this->getTytul().'</td><td rowspan="20" width="150px">'.render($form).'</td></tr>';

i tried everything but my form didn't render there or is invisible and i dont know why

Comment: Hey! Adjusted the reply to output the form to the $description string. Assuming you're actually printing out that $description string somewhere, correct?

Comment: I already solved my problem. I created module which makes my form and functions. To render form I use drupal_render() instead of render() and it works fine 
Thanks for your help :)